# is it possible to convert tensorflow.js model to Tensorflow python model?

Tags: tensorflow.js

Now tensorflow provides tf-converter to convert python model to js model. But it there any way to do this conversion back?

Answer (score 0):

With tfjs-converter it is possible to convert a js layers model to a python layers model and vice-versa. However, it is not possible to convert back to a tensorflow saved model. The [official github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/tree/master/tfjs-converter) describes how to do so